# Wordpress showing 404 error except home page

Tags: wordpress

Here is my coding for .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 301 ^//(.*)$ http://powermatic.com.sg/$1
</IfModule>


# https://wordpress.org/support/topic/font-awesome-not-working?replies=8#post-4921179
# Allow icon font to load on subdomains of WordPress multisite install.

<FilesMatch ".(svg|ttf|otf|woff)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
# END WordPress
```

and this is for the rewriterule

```
<rule name="WordPress: http://powermatic.com.sg" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="http" pattern="powermatic.com.sg" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
```

The wordpress file is located in inetpub/wordpress

I already try the permalink method and change the coding in httpd.conf
To this AllowOverride All

But still unable to access the pages except home page

Please help

Comment: Is there anything written to the error log? What kind of server do you use - the first stuff looks like Apache, the rewrite rule itself looks unfamiliar to me

Comment: There's nothing in error log. I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 standard and IIS 8 , Yes , it is apache

Comment: Why are you using IIS8 **and** Apache? Wouldn't one webserver be enough?

Comment: Hi, Yes, i think i did wrong for this and i now move to my NAS server and only using apache , and i set the permalink to plain and the home page is fine but when i click to sub pages , it show 404 - File or directory not found.
my wordpress location is at web/wordpress
do i need to do anything in .htaccess?

Comment: Hi, I found the issue already, but now for the permalink if i set to plain , it's work fine but i need to set to postname but it show error in sub pages